# Javascript match: stop at second match on /g flag

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to stop at second match instead of letting iterate through whole string?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
var exp = /.../g;
var matches = [
    exp.exec(str),
    exp.exec(str)
];
```

This matches the string two times. See [`exec` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).